# Ruby operator precedence issue

Tags: ruby, operator-precedence

What will the variables 'roses' and 'violets' contain after the following statements are executed?

```
roses = "blue" && "red"
violets = "blue" and "red"
```

I expected roses = "red", violets = "blue", as the precendece order of operators is:

1. &&
2. =
3. and

But the irb shows both of them as "red". Any Explanations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't confuse assigned value and overall value of the expression. Both lines (as whole expressions) evaluate to "red" because there's no short-circuit there and "red" is the last expression evaluated. See for yourself:

```
roses = "blue" && "red" # => "red"
violets = "blue" and "red" # => "red"

roses # => "red"
violets # => "blue"
```

Going further, let's place some parentheses, according to precedence

```
violets = "blue" and "red"
```

becomes

```
(violets = "blue") and "red"
```

becomes

```
("blue") and "red"
```

becomes

```
"red"
```

That's how `violets' gets assigned "blue", but the entire expression evaluates to "red".

Comment: I guess that was just carelessness on my part to not check the actual values stored. Anyways thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

> - Keep in mind that `&&` and `||` operator should be used for boolean expressions evaluation,and/or for control flow evaluations. source:- [`ruby-style-guide`](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide)
> - &&, and, ||, or all are *Short-circuit operators* in Ruby. But `or` has lower precedence than `||`;`and` has has lower precedence than `&&`. source:- [`Boolean operators in various languages`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

---

That said,source:- [`Operator Precedence Table`](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Operator_Precedence)-

> - `&&` and `||` has higher precedence than `=`.Thus your expression `roses = "blue" && "red"` is actually becomes
>     `roses = ("blue" && "red")`
> - `=` has higher precedence than `and` and `or`.Thus your expression `violets = "blue" and "red"` is actually becomes
>     `(violets = "blue") and "red"`